# Getting national phone number instead of international with jQuery plugin intl-tel-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intl-tel-input

I am using the [intl-tel-input jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) in a Rails application.

The input field works nicely, but upon submit, the submitted phone number is in its national form and not in its international form.

The "utils" script is included (using the asset pipeline), and I do not have any special options in the plugin initialization (other than `preferredCountries` and `onlyCountries`).

I am not sure if this is the expected behavior, and if so, what additional steps should be done in order to get the proper, international phone number upon submit.

I am NOT using the rails-specific plugin (there are a few out there), since it had other issues.

My only conclusion so far, is that I have to add some `onSubmit` javascript code to perform something similar to what is mentioned on [this page](https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/national-mode.html), but it feels like a fragile solution to me.

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    $('#patient_phone').val($('#patient_phone').intlTelInput("getNumber"));
  });
  $("#patient_phone").intlTelInput({
    preferredCountries: [...],
    onlyCountries: [...]
  });
});
```

Comment: I see that the docs say that `getNumber` SHOULD return the proper international number, but even on the demo page this seems to be not the case - did you already try to set the option `nationalMode` to `false` or `separateDialCode` to `true` (in that case the "flag field" would contain the prefix)?

Comment: The demo page actually works for me. To my understanding, `nationalMode` is recommended to stay on, since it allows the user to *input* numbers using their accepted national format. I want to keep this behavior. The `separateDialCode` is also something I dont want to see in the input, but I will try tinkering with both to see if it yields any different result that is still user friendly.